# Is it a good idea to use a single-board-computer in a UAV robot?

Tags: robotics

I'm not sure it's good or bad, the robot should have computer vision for SLAM. What's your idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's how we did it when I was in school (albeit nine years ago). You want to focus on algorithms, not learning to program an unfamiliar platform.

Assuming the "A" stands for *aerial*, don't invest in anything you don't want crashing at high speed. And mind the vibrations.

Comment: @Maysam: Anything that's stable and doesn't cause spikes in processor usage should be fine, although that sounds a bit unconventional.

Answer (score 1):

It is a great idea to use a Single Board Computer and [System on Modules](https://www.toradex.com/computer-on-modules) for developing a UAV robot. In fact, it has already been successfully implemented before. I remember seeing a similar implementation of using a Toradex Colibri on Iris Carrier Board for an entry to the Embedded Design Challenge contest by Toradex. Here are the details of the project including the video, updates and source codes at the following link: http://www.challenge.toradex.com/projects/10099-tdxcopter